# How to express the noise of eating melon seeds?

Tags: word-choice

Are there any words or phrases that can express the noise made by melon seeds eaters?

Comment: Dry crunchy melon seeds by the handful, or those direct from the melon, still squishy?

Comment: Dry crunchy seeds

Comment: Is the word "crunched" any good? For word requests, it’s better to show some of your own research as well as an example sentence. If "crunched" isn’t any good, you could edit your question to say why.

Comment: Do you mean straight from the melon or after being roasted?

Comment: Roasted melon seeds. I have accepted the answer suggested by Pam, thank you anyway:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Crunched**.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crunch):

> to crush hard food loudly between the teeth, or to make a sound as if something is being crushed or broken:
>
> She was crunching noisily on an apple.
>
> The gravel crunched underfoot as we walked up to the house.

Synonyms include "munch".

Comment: I'd vote this up except for the synonym suggestion. *munch* = *eat*, and doesn't say much if anything about the quality of the noise ("steadily and often audibly" says Oxford).